# Julia's Serialize which save DataFrame to file doesn't work on long file name

Tags: serialization, julia

I've made file storage system by Julia. It is to save DataFrame format as a file. It's being saved through Serialize. However, Serialize makes an error when the file name is long. How can I solve? Here is an example. I think save and load sytem of JuliaDB has same problem. Long file name error.

```
using Serialization

df=DataFrame(c1=[5,6,7])

folderName="C:\\ChamGo\\ADGOIMMUGYUL2_2_OIL_STS_SL01_WONCHEON\\WON_IDv1v36869vEPOCHMSv63602211600000v63602985600000\\WON_IDv1v36869vEPOCHMSv63602211600000v63602985600000\\WON_IDv1v36869vEPOCHMSv63602211600000v63602985600000"

mkpath(folderName)

fileName="C:\\ChamGo\\ADGOIMMUGYUL2_2_OIL_STS_SL01_WONCHEON\\WON_IDv1v36869vEPOCHMSv63602211600000v63602985600000\\WON_IDv1v36869vEPOCHMSv63602211600000v63602985600000\\WON_IDv1v36869vEPOCHMSv63602211600000v63602985600000\\WON_IDv1v36869vEPOCHMSv63602211600000v63602985600000.jls"

serialize(fileName,df)  ## It makes an error.

#############

fileName="C:\\ChamGo\\shortName.jls"

serialize(fileName,df)  ## It's not.
```

Comment: This sounds filesystem related. NTFS has a limit of 255 for a filename, though the path should be allowed to be much longer. But it's a possible source where `serialize` trips up. It would as always be useful to see the exact error, with the entire stack trace.